# XML to HTML problems

Tags: javascript, xml, xls

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="movies.xsl"?>
<root>
<Diary>
<Event EventName="J.Edgar" Classification="2011 Movies" EventStart="2012-03-19T07:00:00+00:00" EventEnd="2012-03-19T08:00:00+00:00" />
<Event EventName="Titanic" Classification="1997 Movies" EventStart="2012-03-19T09:00:00+00:00" EventEnd="2012-03-19T10:00:00+00:00" />
</Diary>
</root>
```

I have this two options for creating what I need:

1. > ```
   > <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
   >
   > <xsl:template match="Event">
   >   <html>
   >   <body>
   >   <h2>Best movies</h2>
   >   <p>Here you can find the top movies ever.</p>
   >   <table border="1">
   >     <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
   >       <th>Movie</th>
   >       <th>Year</th>
   >       <th>Start Time</th>
   >       <th>End Time</th>
   >     </tr>
   >     <tr>
   >       <td><xsl:value-of select="@EventName"/></td>
   >       <td><xsl:value-of select="@Classification"/></td>
   >       <td><xsl:value-of select="@EventStart"/></td>
   >       <td><xsl:value-of select="@EventEnd"/></td>
   >     </tr>
   >   </table>
   >   </body>
   >   </html>
   > </xsl:template>
   >
   > </xsl:stylesheet>
   > ```

2.

```
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadXMLDoc(fName){
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                    xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xhttp.open("GET",fName,false);
                xhttp.send("");
                return xhttp.responseXML;
            }

            xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("movies.xml");

            function displayEvents(){
                var eventsO = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Event");
                var tableO = document.createElement('table'), newRow, newCell;
                for(i=0; i<eventsO.length; i++){
                    newRow = tableO.insertRow(-1);
                    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
                    newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(eventsO[i].getAttribute('EventName')));
                    newCell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
                    newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(eventsO[i].getAttribute('Classification')));
                }
                document.body.appendChild(tableO);
            }
            window.onload=displayEvents;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Can you please try to correct me in these codes?

I would like to do the following features:

1. load an external xml from another site anl not local.
2. Have the list of movies and that when you press on a movie, a popup or a new page comes up and you have more info about the movie. But how do I create it dynamically so the information in that pop up will stay the same but the name of the movie will change, based on the movie you clicked..?
3. the match "Event" is working but maybe it's wrong.. (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be an xsl:for-each to display the movies in a loop, as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Best movies</h2>
  <p>Here you can find the top movies ever.</p>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Movie</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Start Time</th>
      <th>End Time</th>
    </tr>

    <xsl:for-each select="root/Diary/Event">      
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@EventName"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@Classification"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@EventStart"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="@EventEnd"/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>

  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I will check this now. 

I understand that the xls is like a css for XML files, but how then will be the URL of the page for my users?
example.com/something.xml ?
example.com/something.xls ?
example.com/something/ ?

How do I attach this XML file to a page on my site when it's ready?

Thanks!

Comment: Your advice works, thank you! Can you tell me how can I import an XML from another site and not a local one?

Comment: I think, in your situation, you could use a server side language like PHP, where you can fetch that XML file using a simple function. Let me give you a PHP example: 1. Create a file named 'get_xml.php'.  2. Put this content `<?php header ("content-type: text/xml"); $url = $_GET['url']; $xml = file_get_contents($url); /* modify the xml and insert xsl stylesheet definition, and then output modified xml */ echo $xml; ?>` does this make sense?

Comment: I cannot do on the same html page that I am using: $xml = file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/feed/); and then             xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("$xml"); ?? Thanks!

Comment: there you go, remember, **loadXMLDoc** is a client side function (JavaScript). So, in your HTML file, within JavaScript tag, you call it as: `xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("get_xml.php?url=http://example.com/feed");` get_xml.php is the local file you'd create.

Comment: I am trying like this: $url = $_GET['http://example.com/feed']; 
Is it ok? why are we using the GET?

Comment: we use $_GET so that it will be more dynamic. If you have only one feed url, you can simply use it as `$url = 'http://example.com/feed'; $xml = file_get_contents($url);` and then you won't have to append the 'url' parameter when you request 'get_xml.php'. i.e: you'll call the function as : `xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("get_xml.php");`